# Confirm method using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi everyone I am having a problem with the confirm method in HTML(creating a button). Here is the link to codepen https://codepen.io/gat-yvon-josua/pen/abOPeEw

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

This is my JavaScript code

```
function clickme() {
  confirm('do you accept Jesus');
}
var choice = confirm("do you accept Jesus");

if ( choice == true){
  alert("you pressed ok");
}
else {
  alert("are you sure you want to cancel");
}
```

The following is my CSS code.

```
h1 {
  font-family: palatino;
  color: dimgray;
}
div {
  width: 140pt;
  padding: 5pt;
  Margin: 10pt;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
#div2 {
background-color:#FF00FF;
}
```

- At last this is my HTML code

  ## Jesus is King

  He saves souls
      
      
        Allow him today

Comment: it is working. What do you want to happen exactly?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you just want to keep all the code inside a function so that your choice variable is locally scoped to that function.

#### Solution

In other words, change your Javascript to to the following:

```js
function clickme() {
  let choice = confirm('do you accept Jesus');
  if (choice) {
    alert("you pressed ok");
  }
  else {
    alert("are you sure you want to cancel");
  }
}
```

If this is not the desired behavior you seek, please update your question with what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should call *and handle* `confirm` within the event handler. In your code `confirm` is loaded on document load and within the handler, but the result is not handled within the handler.

Furthermore: it's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers

```js
document.querySelector(`button#clicker`).addEventListener(`click`, confirmMe);

function confirmMe(evt) {
  const result = document.querySelector(`div#result`);
  result.textContent = confirm('do you accept that dogs bark?') ? `Good for you` : `I understand`;
  //                   ^ returns a boolean, so use the answer to determine action
}
```

```html
<button id="clicker">Acceptance</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```